# Call 'created' function from 'methods' in VueJS after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I AM NEW TO **VUE JS**
My VueJS app structure goes like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    //HTML CODE
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {

  },
  methods: {
   functionABC(){
   // CAN I CALL created() in this function ?
   }
  },
  created() {
    //SOME FUNCTIONS
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I know that I can make a function of all the operations happening on first page load in created() and then call that function everytime i need  and that will also serve the purpose but I actually want to know the proper way to call the created() function even after the page is loaded

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can't. If there is a way to do it I think that is not recommended. You should do a function and call it from created or from another function to not duplicate code

Comment: Then there must be a way to load the component again as we do in ngOnInIt() in angular

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use `Vue-router`, every time you switch to a different route, the old route (and its component) get's destroyed (unless you use the `<keep-alive>` tag). That means that if you have 2 routes and switch back and forth, the `created()` method gets called with every new route hit.

For demonstration I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-routing-example-1wiy0). In the sandbox there are 2 components: `Hello.vue` and `Goodbye.vue`. In both of them there is a `console.log`. If you switch between the routes, you'll see that every time you switch, the message gets logged to the console. Meaning that the created method get's called.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question I am asking about calling the created(){} in one of my methods on the same page.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I should've explained more. Long story short, it isn't possible. The only time the created method get's called is when a vue instance / component is created. That's why I made the sandbox example :-). See here for more info about Vue Lifecycle hooks and when they're called:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks